# Proving the inequality of two distributions after multiplying its ratio

Tags: inequality

I have two lists $A$, $B$ where two have the same number of elements, and all elements in A are larger than that of B and all elements in A and B are positive and the sum of each list is larger than 1.

Obviously, the sum of the lists has following inequality.

$$\sum_{t=1}^{N}A_t  > \sum_{t=1}^{N}B_t$$

where $N$ is the number of elements. Then, I calculate the ratio of the elements as follows.

$$
\alpha_t = \frac{A_t}{\sum_{k=1}{A_k}}, \beta_t = \frac{B_t}{\sum_{k=1}{B_k}} 
$$

Then, I multiply the calculated ratio to each element in each set. My question is that the below inequality is still correct? or the inequality can be changed?

$$\sum_{t=1}^{N}\alpha_t \cdot A_t  > \sum_{t=1}^{N}\beta_t \cdot B_t $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_t\alpha_t=\sum_t\beta_t=1$$ Hence
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^{N}\alpha_t \cdot A_t&=\dfrac{\sum_{t=1}^{N}\alpha_t \cdot A_t}{\sum_t \alpha_t}\\
&  > \min_t A_t\\
&>\max_t B_t\\
&> \dfrac{ \sum_{t=1}^{N}\beta_t \cdot B_t}{\sum_t\beta_t}\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^{N}\beta_t \cdot B_t\end{align}
Because irrespective of the weights, weighted average of a list with each element higher is always more than weighted average of the other list.

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for clear answer!

Comment: You're welcome!